# How can I get the date part only? I do not need the time when it selects the date picker

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value from date-picker. It shows the time and date. I need to display date only, not time.

```
var start = $("#min").datepicker("getDate"),
end = $("#max").datepicker("getDate"),
currentDate = new Date(start),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
You can specify wich format that the datepicker should return when initializing.

To set the presentation to output something "2014-03-15" you initialize your datepicker using:

```
 $("#min").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });
```

Where the letters specify your output format:

```
yy = year (In four numbers)
mm = month (Months with leading zero)
dd = day (day/date with leading zero)
```

Or some similar format depending on your preferences.

You can then get the value using:

```
 $("#min").val();
```

Using $("#max").datepicker("getDate") will return a date object. wich you also can use but it need further parsing. Personaly I think for your needs that would be overkill.

### Full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gu3QA/

**Edit**

Alternative method  to parse Date to format "D M m yy":

```
function formatDate(date){
    var weekday=new Array(7);
     weekday[0]="Sun";
     weekday[1]="Mon";
     weekday[2]="Tue";
     weekday[3]="Wed";
     weekday[4]="Thu";
     weekday[5]="Fri";
     weekday[6]="Sat";

    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    var month = (date.getMonth()) + 1;
    month = "0" + month; 
    month = month.slice(-2);
    var out = weekday[date.getDay()] + " " + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " "  + month + " " + date.getFullYear();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: plase tell me in more details

Comment: Also added a demo fiddle.

Comment: you havn't done what i said in my answer in the fiddle. Try that. It will work!

Comment: To have that format, change "yy-mm-dd" => "D M m yy"

Comment: still its not working  --still workink like this "Thu Mar 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"---check the  filejsfiddle.net/uScc2/6

Comment: thats since you're still getting the date using .datepicker("getDate") not .val()!

Comment: please check filejsfiddle.net/uScc2/6 and tell me where the change needs

Comment: Dont really have time to read your whole code. But read your fiddle and added a function that will make it work in THIS instance. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uScc2/7/ This method is using the Date object and parses the result for your specifik needs.

Comment: hai philip, thx for ur feedback but i really need like "Sun Mar 23 2014 " this format

Answer (score 2):

$('#min').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

**For further reference:**

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: var start = $("#min").datepicker("getDate"),
            end = $("#max").datepicker("getDate"),
            currentDate = new Date(start),
            between = [];                           what change needs here???